# Node.js IPC tutoruals

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, ipc

There are several cluster/IPC libraries for node.js like multi node or node cluster. I'd like to figure out how they work, but there is lack of good tutorials/docs/manuals about IPC in node.js. Without them it is kind of hard to read all this barely commented and documented source code for a new person in node.js like me. Can someone provide some links to tutorials or docs if there any of them exists?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Well the ones I know( cluster : http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/ , robtweed : https://github.com/robtweed/Q-Oper8 ) have enough documentation. Just ask what's missing from them.